# Add zero to the left of Integer

Tags: java, string, integer, zero

How can I get an Integer number with a zero to the left. For example I create a class **Date** that has an Integer variable with name month. I wanna to sent a number from MainMethod to class and get the number back with zero to the left `System.out.println(date1.getMonth());`.

```
this.month = Integer.parseInt(String.format("%02d", monthFromMain));
```

This code above print always out the number of monthFromMain.

Comment: you can't append zero in int from left. you must store this value into String.

Comment: Your title says zero "to the right," but your question mentions "to the left."  Which one do you actually want?  Note that integers don't have insignificant zeroes to the left, so if you want that, you'll have to use a string as the above comment suggests.

Comment: Why not use something made for date formatting? E.g. `new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(date1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to handle months with leading zero. Like if you get month `9` to be parsed in Month format `09` and to be Integer , which is impossible of course.

Here is one tip how to add leading zero to integer: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/02/add-leading-zeros-to-integers-Java-String-left-padding-example-program.html

But then it would have to be string of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
new DecimalFormat("00").format(monthFromMain)
```

Comment: Where should I put this code. Do you mean in the class Date.

Comment: new DecimalFormat("00").format(monthFromMain);
            this.month = Integer.parseInt(new DecimalFormat("00").format(monthFromMain));

Comment: this piece of code will return you your month formatted in two digits.

Comment: He doesn't want that , he wants to have integer with 0 in front, which is impossible.